# Merging datasets by name when names have different formats in R

Tags: r, merge, fuzzy-search, agrep

I have two different dataframes in R that I am trying to merge together. One is just a set of names and the other is a set of names with corresponding information about each person.

So say I want to take this first dataframe:

```
Name
1. Blow, Joe
2. Smith, John
3. Jones, Tom 
etc....
```

and merge it to this one:

```
   DonorName  CandidateName DonationAmount CandidateParty
1   blow joe Bush, George W          3,000     Republican
2   guy some  Obama, Barack          5,000       Democrat
3 smith john    Reid, Harry          4,000       Democrat
```

such that I'd have a new list that includes only people on my first list with the information from the second. Were the two "Name" values formatted in the same way, I could just use merge(), but would there be a way to somehow use agrep() or pmatch() to do this?

Also, the 2nd dataframe I'm working with has about 25 million rows in it and 6 columns, so would making a for loop be the fastest way to go about this?

Reproducible versions of the example data:

```
first <- data.frame(Name=c("Blow, Joe","Smith, John","Jones, Tom"),
         stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

second <- read.csv(text="
DonorName|CandidateName|DonationAmount|CandidateParty
blow joe|Bush, George W|3,000|Republican
guy some|Obama, Barack|5,000|Democrat
smith john|Reid, Harry|4,000|Democrat",header=TRUE,sep="|",
stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Comment: Are your formats always the same in each dataset, or do they vary within each set?

Comment: @StanO has this question been answered which an effective solution? if not please suggest what's need otherwise accept the appropriate solution or write+accept your own if it's not provided below

Comment: Sorry, I thought I had checked your answer, but it seems I didn't. Belated thanks for the great advice on this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### solution:

```
first$DonorName <- gsub(", "," ",tolower(first$Name),fixed=TRUE)

require(dplyr)

result <- inner_join(first,second,by="DonorName")
```

will give you what you need if the data is as you've provided it.

```
result
         Name  DonorName  CandidateName DonationAmount CandidateParty
1   Blow, Joe   blow joe Bush, George W          3,000     Republican
2 Smith, John smith john    Reid, Harry          4,000       Democrat
```

#### *"fast way to go about this"*

The `dplyr` method as above:

```
f_dplyr <- function(left,right){
   left$DonorName <- gsub(", "," ",tolower(left$Name),fixed=TRUE)
   inner_join(left,right,by="DonorName")
}
```

`data.table` method, setting key on first.

```
f_dt <- function(left,right){
   left[,DonorName :=  gsub(", "," ",tolower(Name),fixed=TRUE)]
   setkey(left,DonorName)
   left[right,nomatch=0L]
}
```

`data.table` method, setting both keys.

```
f_dt2 <- function(left,right){
   left[,DonorName :=  gsub(", "," ",tolower(Name),fixed=TRUE)]
   setkey(left,DonorName)
   setkey(right,DonorName)
   left[right,nomatch=0L]
}
```

`base` method relying on `sapply`:

```
f_base <- function(){
  second[second$DonorName %in%
  sapply(tolower(first[[1]]), gsub, pattern = ",", replacement = "", fixed = TRUE), ]
}
```

let's make second df a bit more realistic at 1M obs for a fairish comparision:

```
second <- cbind(second[rep(1:3,1000000),],data.frame(varn= 1:1000000))
left <- as.data.table(first)
right <- as.data.table(second)

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
          f_base(),
          f_dplyr(first,second),
          f_dt(left,right),
          f_dt2(left,right),
          times=20)
```

And we get:

```
Unit: milliseconds
                   expr       min        lq    median        uq       max neval
               f_base() 2880.6152 3031.0345 3097.3776 3185.7903 3904.4649    20
 f_dplyr(first, second)  292.8271  362.7379  454.6864  533.9147  774.1897    20
      f_dt(left, right)  489.6288  531.4152  605.4148  788.9724 1340.0016    20
     f_dt2(left, right)  472.3126  515.4398  552.8019  659.7249  901.8133    20
```

On my machine, with this *?contrived* example we gain about *2.5 seconds over `base` methods*. `sapply` simplifies and doesn't scale very well in my experience... this gap likely gets bigger when you increase the number of unique groups in `first` and `second`.

**Please feel free to edit if you come up with more efficient use**. I don't pretend to know, but I always try to learn something.

Comment: Nice, but this only covers one aspect of benchmarking - namely large number of rows. It has a total of 5 unique groups. [Here's a gist](https://gist.github.com/arunsrinivasan/db6e1ce05227f120a2c9) illustrating other two factors that I've come to know of from various benchmarks - number of unique groups and the number of columns the join is performed on.

Comment: @Arun I suspected it may be the case that punches be traded depending on the data structure. Now I think the philosophies are _?fundamentally_ different but I would certainly find the idea that some friendly competition + a wealth of public fair comparisons be provided as documentation on both repositories homepages. Dare I say a great time waster would be a hosted `Shiny` app?

Comment: Right. It's just very time consuming, especially covering all cases. I've attempted quite a few cases already though. Hopefully we'll get them out on our homepage sometime soon.

Comment: @Arun. Well you know us end users, parasitic behaviour built in. That being said, perhaps it would be interesting to just start a shared repo that acts simply as a "results dump". So anyone could submit their gist / pull request (say in the form of a cached .rmd) of a specific comparison on their own machine and then maintainers can validate before merging in. Then you also get to see how reproducible a comparison (experiment) is across not just one user but a community of users. just FFT (_food for thought_).

Comment: One big problem with that is, I don't consider benchmarking 'ms' or 'us' as much useful (on tools developed for large data). I'd like to *stress test* and see where each one breaks. I've been benchmarking on 1/2 - 1 billion rows with varying group size. I (and others can) see very clearly how well each tool scales or breaks.

Answer (score 0):

Without `dplyr`:

```
second[second$DonorName %in%
  sapply(tolower(first[[1]]), gsub, pattern = ",", replacement = "", fixed = TRUE), ]
```

Result:

```
#     DonorName  CandidateName DonationAmount CandidateParty
# 1   blow joe  Bush, George W          3,000     Republican
# 3 smith john     Reid, Harry          4,000       Democrat
```